# C, Get wanted element from string

Tags: c

I have char array that contains information like so (which is basically string) :

```
char arr[] = "Age: 22 Height: 180 Weight: 80";
```

I want to get specific information from this Char array. For example i need Height number (which would be 180 in this case) and store it in another Char array.

I can get to "Height: 180 Wei...." by using.

```
strstr(arr,"Height: ");
```

but i need to get rid of the end and have just plain "180" number

I know i should be using sub string or other similar functions that split the string. but i just don't imagine how to solve this.
Any ideas ?
Thank you

Comment: Try using [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/).

Comment: So, that's why I said `sscanf` not `scanf`(for stdin) or `fscanf`(for disk files).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need the numbers, use `sscanf()`:

```
int age, height, weight;
const int result = sscanf(arr, "Age: %d Height: %d Weight: %d", &age, &height, &weight);

if (result < 3) // error: couldn't match all elements
```

Comment: This is good, but the return value of `sscanf()` should also be checked before relying on the values.

Comment: You can also use it the way used in the code example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/): This removes the dependency on the text part of the string.

Comment: this will not make me enter elements ? cuz i need to extract them from string

Comment: Andrius:  `scanf()` reads from `stdin` (user input, unless redirected).  What I'm suggesting here is `sscanf()` (note the extra `s`).  That version operates on an input string that you've already loaded.

Comment: oh didnt know that. Thanks ill try it :). one more question. Would it work with letters instead of numbers ?

Comment: @creichen Nice edit. I'd make `result` a `const` too for good measure, of course. :)

Comment: @Andrius, yes, in principle, but you'll have to use different formatting specs (`%c` for chars, `%5s` for strings of at most 5 characters and so on, where the string is considered to end whenever a whitespace character is encountered).  You may want to check the man page for details: http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf

Answer (score 0):

```
char *height_with_label = strstr(arr,"Height: ");
size_t label_len = strlen("Height: ");
int height = default_value;
if (height_with_label)
{
    height = atoi(height_with_label + label_len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an integer `h` to `0`.

Iterate through the characters following `"Height "`. Test whether the character is a digit. If it's a digit, multiply `h` by 10 and add that digit, else end the iteration.

No functions necessary. If you want to use a function to make your life easier, read a reference guide on the C standard library, such as the one on [The GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer to point to the end of the "`height:`" word like this:

```
char *p = strstr(arr, "height:") + strlen("height:");
```

Then use the atof function in string library to get the rest of the array as a float. It will stops at the first undefined char (a non numerical character) and it will gets you the value of the height.

```
float height = atof(p);
```

You can use `atoi` to get an integer instead of a float or `atol` to get a long integer.

Make sure to include the stdlib.h library to use these functions.

The same think for the other numerical informations.